# Adding a Foreign Key to an existing Table

Tags: sql, key, alter

I forgot to add a column which is a foreign key. I tried doing the following:

```
ALTER TABLE GamesTbl
ADD Console varchar(30) NOT NULL,
INDEX (Console), FOREIGN KEY(Console) references ConsolesTbl(ConsoleName) ON DELETE          CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Edit:

I tried adding the field first and after that the constraint like so:

```
ALTER TABLE GamesTbl
ADD Column Console varchar(30);
ADD CONSTRAINT Console FOREIGN KEY (Console)
REFERENCES ConsolesTbl(ConsoleName);
```

Comment: Use two commands.  One adds the column.  The second adds the contstraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to add the missing column, an index, and also add a foreign key constraint. AFAIK there isn't one single command to do all this all in one go. I would do this in smaller steps :)

Also, note that if the Games Table already has data in it, you will not be able to add a `NOT NULL` column to it without also setting a default.

Here's one way to do this, viz by adding the missing column as `NULL`able, setting data, and then changing it to `NOT NULL`:

(I'm also assuming MySql)

```
ALTER TABLE GamesTbl ADD Console varchar(30) NULL;
ALTER TABLE GamesTbl ADD FOREIGN KEY(Console) references ConsolesTbl(ConsoleName) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
CREATE INDEX IX1_GamesConsole ON GamesTbl(Console);

UPDATE GamesTbl SET Console = 'Playstation'; 
ALTER TABLE GamesTbl CHANGE COLUMN Console Console varchar(30) NOT NULL;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/124b3/2)